# Is my notation correct?

Tags: logic, notation

$\{x : x \le 75, \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \cup \{0\}\}$

Is this notation correct? I'm going for positive integers less than or equal to $75$ including $0$.

Comment: No, its $\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} : x\leq 75\}$, or $\{x\in\mathbb{N}_0: x\leq 75\}$.

Comment: Thanks! What notation do I use to convey that the domain of x is that set?

Comment: What do you mean by *domain* of $x$? Domain refers to a function...?

Comment: sorry the domain of f(x) i meant

Comment: @stange: really? I always thaught that $\mathbb{N}_0$ means $\mathbb{N}$ **without** zero, not **with** zero.

Comment: Then you can write "Let $D$ be the domain of $f(x)$". It is the fastest and most convenient way. Otherwise, you can write "$\{x : f(x)\text{ is defined }\}$" which is both ugly and slow.

Comment: @Dominique If you denote with $\mathbb{N}$ the set of natural numbers without $0$, then $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, and if $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers including zero, then $\mathbb{N}^\ast = \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Thats at least the notation I know of.

Comment: @stange: here (in Belgium) it's just the contrary: $\mathbb{N}$ **always** contains zero, but $\mathbb{N}_0$ does not.

Comment: @Dominique, that is quite surprising to me! I haven't ever done maths in Belgium though. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1589800/473276), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709802/473276) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation) all agree with the convention I'm familiar with, that $0 \in \Bbb N_0$. For me notations like $\Bbb N^*$ and $\Bbb Z_{>0}$ would explicitly exclude $0$. I'm not able to find any source at all stating the convention that $0 \notin \Bbb N_0$. Could you point me to one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this question. 1) Is your notation *correct* regarding "mathematical grammar" and 2) Is your notation recommended?

For the first question, "$\{x:x\leq75, \in\mathbb{Z}_+\cup\{0\}\}$" is wrong. You wrote "$\in\mathbb{Z}_+\cup\{0\}$. This is where the error lies. What is $\in\mathbb{Z}_+\cup\{0\}$? You have to write a variable in front. Hence, writing $\{x:x\leq75, x\in\mathbb{Z}_+\cup\{0\}\}$ would be *correct* regarding "mathematical grammar". You can write like this and people would understand.

For the second question, it is not recommend to write like this. Usually, we write the *set* that the number belongs to in front. Note that *set* refers to sets like $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$ etc, those that are already defined. Hence, the correct notation will be $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}:x\leq 75\}$. Or, you can just write $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\cap[0, 75]$.

Comment: @ℤ_INT I have edited my answer. Please check out the new and more complete answer.